# Several Linux Distributions are hanging on boot - NVidia Graphics

Tags: linux, boot, laptop, nvidia-graphics-card

I've just bought a new laptop, I used Linux on my old laptop for 15 months with no problems, but the new laptop has had problems now with several distributions. The laptop fails to boot up ~2/3 of the time and just hangs on a black screen. I have searched for this problem around, there seems to be a million different solutions, none of which have worked for me. I have narrowed it down to NVidia Graphics (I think), but after installing the NVidia drivers it pretty much stopped working at all.

System Information; 
Lenovo IdeaPad Z580 
Intel i5 processor 
8GB RAM 
other OS; Win8x64 
distributions tried: Ubuntu, Mint, Elementary 
Just want to get a Linux working because it is SO much faster for doing development on. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please give us some more details. Black screens during install is a _classic_ issue, usually solved by adding grub options like `acpi=off` or `noapic`. Does the black screen happen when you install or after installation? What are the exact steps taken to reproduce the error?

Comment: Ubuntu has a great community website with people very familar with getting Ubuntu to work on any number of configurations.  Have you tried there?  You have not provided us enough information to help.

Comment: Black screen happens around 2/3 of the time, first when trying to run the LiveCD then after it has installed as well. It literally happens when I boot the laptop and once I have gone past grub I just get a black screen. I will try to boot in recovery mode and give you a trace if you like?

Comment: Have you tried any of the "million different solutions"? Which ones? Tell us what you've tried and how so we don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I've tried adding nomodeset to grub, and nvidia/nouveau modeset. I've also tried updating NVidia drivers to version 325 (latest from NVidia).

Comment: @dpaterson1 - What about the Intel HD Graphics 4000 drivers?

Answer (score 1):

For everybody's information, this was solved by re-installing linux and adding 'noapic' to the grub boot line